# Canonical example of non-Hausdorff Ellis group

Tags: dynamical-systems, separation-axioms

Given a dynamical system (that is, for me, a group $G$ acting by homeomorphisms on a compact Hausdorff space $X$), the Ellis group (which can be defined in terms of the universal minimal flow ([as here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Topological_dynamics#The_Galois_theory_of_minimal_flows)), or just as the ideal group of the enveloping semigroup of the dynamical system) has a natural compact $T_1$ topology, which makes it a semitopological group.

I've seen claims that the topology is typically not $T_2$, but no examples. Are there any specific examples where it is not hard to see that the Ellis group is not Hausdorff?